# How to fix Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.6.21'] was not found?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.6.21'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.21'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

project structure :
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Xlb.png)

Comment: Failed to reproduce the problem. Please, attach a link to a sample project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The same issue: android, kotlin, multimodule project. Devs here discuss gradle snap version as possible root cause https://github.com/snapcrafters/gradle/issues/19